# Find clique with maximum node value in graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, graph-theory

I have a graph of nodes assigned with a certain value. I wish to find the clique in the graph with the maximum sum of nodes (note not necessarily the maximum clique)

One approach I thought of would be a greedy algorithm that:

1. Select the largest node from the graph
2. Select the largest next node such that it is connected to all the previously selected nodes if the sum of the nodes increases.
3. Repeat 2 until the sum does not increase any more

However, this approach does not lead to correctness as you could imagine a graph with a clique of 8 nodes all of value 1, and a single node of value 7. The correct answer here is 8, not 7. My actual problem has a complex graph but here are some examples of the desired result with the actual graph and the biggest sum, which I found manually:

[image]
[image]

Here is a simpler example with the solution:

[image][image]

What would be the best graph representation and an efficient and correct way to solve this problem in python on an arbitrary graph in a representation of your choice in python *without libraries*?

Comment: I do not believe that a greedy approach you give is actually correct as you suppose you had a graph with a clique of 8 "ones" and a single node of 6. Then you would return 6 if you did this greedy algorithm when the correct answer is 8. You need to do a dynamic programming approach. Also some graphs you give are directed and some undirected. Which is it - it will matter for the solution I provide

Comment: The solution is the second graph in which the arrow shows the order in which the nodes have been traversed. The actual graph is undirected (the ones with the larger number of edges)

Comment: Yes. I did not know the terminology, but I think what I need is to get a clique with the maximum sum of nodes from the graph if I am understanding correctly (in response to the deleted comment)

Comment: Your question is unclear. Your description does not appear to match the graphs which you have included.

Comment: Can you clarify? Are you looking for a strictly decreasing sequence If not, the simpler second example you give could be `8-4-7`. So does the sequence you give have to be monotonic (i.e strictly decreasing) or do all of the nodes have to be connected to all other nodes (i.e clique)

Comment: Not a strictly decreasing sequence. But since 7 and 8 are not adjacent, 7 cannot be in the sequence

Comment: So the result does have to be super-connected. Got you.

Comment: @modesitt Can you possibly edit the question a bit so that the terminologies are correct? I haven't had a course in graph theory yet, so I am unfamiliar with some of these terms

Comment: @Yuki.kuroshita moderators would need to unlock the question, but I would recomend using [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-2.0/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.clique.find_cliques.html#networkx.algorithms.clique.find_cliques) and calling `find_cliques` on the graph after you create it. Then iterate over all cliques, taking the sum of all positive numbers in that clique and returning the sum with the highest value over all cliques. This will be correct and efficient as the find_cliques method of networkx has a decent implementation.

Comment: @modesitt I have to understand the algorithm, and I am not allowed to use any libraries. I thought what I was thinking was right, but as you said, it is not always correct. I do not require a complete code, I just need to basically understand how to do this. I can look into algorithms for finding cliques and then doing as you suggested. And thank you so much for the numerous edits

Comment: @Makyen, I think now the question has been reworded correctly so that it is clear now, and is not too broad, and the description is better